# Give agents different priorities in a queue

Tags: anylogic

In my AnyLogic simulation model, I have two sources and going through two service blocks in a closed loop. At starting time I inject 1 50T Truck and 2 20T Trucks.

Descriptive image here:

[Image of Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WM2G.png)

At the second service block, "crusher1", I want the queue to always prioritize the agent "truck50ts" over "truck20ts". How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `Service` block with `Seize`, `Queue`, `Delay` and `Release` blocks (same as a `Service` but more options for you).

in the `Queue` properties, set the queue priority to "agent comparison".

In the conditional code, write `agent1 instanceof Truck_50tons ? true : false` as below:
[image]

This assumes your 50t truck is an agent of a custom agent type called `Truck_50tons` (create those at the sources)

Comment: Ok, did the alterations. 

But, does this mean that if a 20T truck is already in the queue, then the 50T truck will not move past it in the queue?

The behavior I want in the end is that 50T trucks "sneak" past 20T trucks if they are already in the queue when the 50T truck arrives.

Comment: This is exactly what happens. But in the future, you should get into the habit of testing this yourself with a simple example model. Much better learning experience. Also, this is described in the help for queues ;)

Comment: @TellefSolberg, if this was helpful, please flag the answer as "useful" (up arrow next to it) so others find it easier in the future ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks. The problem was that my queue size always remained at 0 due to a 'seize' being the main queue instead. All sorted now though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TellefSolberg if this was helpful, please flag the answer as "useful" (up arrow next to it) so others find it easier in the future ;)

Comment: I would, but I do not have enough reputation points it seems :/